# \usebeamerfont introduces extra space

Tags: beamer, spacing

I have a (probably trivial) question about `\usebeamerfont`.

I want to use this command inside a `\mbox` and it somehow produces extra space compared to the manual change of font. Here comes my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamerfont*{A}{size=\Large}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \fbox{\Large a}
        \fbox{\usebeamerfont{A} a}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I would really appreciate an explanation of this behaviour.

Comment: That's because you have a space in there.  Try `\fbox{\usebeamerfont{A}a}`

Comment: Oh. Yeah, I see :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because there is an extra space in there ¯_(ツ)_/¯. I thought, this command was non-space-sensitive...

Comment: In fact, it does provide an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I had not understood. +1